# How can I convert this imweb ( Image type) to base64?

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-web

Image imweb;
i want to convert this into base64. please help

```
imweb = (await FlutterWebImagePicker.getImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the package

```
import 'dart: convert';
```

Then call

```
List<int> bytes = imweb.readAsBytesSync();
String imageBase64 = base64Encode(imweb);
```